# Finding the limit of a radical function without conjugates

Tags: calculus, limits

I am a first year differential calculus student and I was solving a problem where I had to find $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x)$$

I have been solving these types of problems by factoring out the highest degree x, like this:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty} 
\sqrt{x^2\biggl(1-{\frac5x}+{\frac1{x^2} \biggr)}}-x 
&= \lim_{x\to \infty} x 
\biggl(\sqrt{(1-{\frac5x}+{\frac1{x^2}}}-1\biggr) \\ 
&= (\infty) 
\biggl(\sqrt{(1-{\frac5{\infty}}+{\frac1{\infty^2}}}-1\biggr) \\ 
&= (\infty) \bigl(\sqrt{1} -1) \\ 
&= 0 
\end{align}

But desmos shows that the right answer is found by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate to get $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(-5x +1)}{(\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}+x)} = -2.5$$

My question is why do we need to multiply by the conjugate here to get the right answer, whereas just factoring works for similar limits like $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+7x}}{11-2x} $$

If the original expression is algebraically the same after multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate, how could I have solved the limit without involving conjugates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\infty \cdot 0 \neq 0$

Comment: Notation: use `\infty` for $\infty$ and surround math in double `$$` to display it.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to elaborate my comment here:

The method works, but the reason your answer was wrong was because you multiplied $0$ and $\infty$.

The reason factoring out the highest degree of $x$ worked for the limit in your second example is because it did not involve multiplying $\infty$ and $0$. This form is indeterminate and therefore cannot be simplified to any value.

Answer (score 1):

I want to apply a method that works as follows, which does not use conjugates . But, please note that I am *not* a calculus student . Therefore, it would be instructive for me to get *feedback* from mathematics students or experts in the comments to find out how rigorous/accurate the method I used in this answer is .

---

Let $u$ be a new variable such that $x^2-5x+1=(x-u)^2$ . Then, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&u^2-2ux+5x-1=0\\
\implies &x=\frac {1-u^2}{5-2u}=\frac {1/u-u}{5/u-2}\end{align}
$$

Thus, we can replace $\color{#c00}{x\to\infty}$ as $\color{#0a0}{u\to \infty}$ . Then, the original function can be written as follows :

$$
\begin{align}f(x):&=|x-u|-x\\
&=\frac{u^2-5u+1}{2u-5}-\frac {1-u^2}{5-2u}\\
&=-\frac {5u-2 }{2u-5}=-\frac {5-2/u}{2-5/u}\end{align}
$$

Therefore, we *can* conclude that the original limit becomes :

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{u\to\infty}-\frac {5-2/u}{2-5/u}=-\frac 52\thinspace\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice, but I'm not sure I follow 100%. By expressing "x" in terms of "u" using the equation you created in the first line, you were able to rewrite the entire original function in terms of u, correct? So, the graph of f as a function of u will have the same shape as f(x), and that's why you were able to take u to infinity instead of x?

Comment: I think, this way is mind confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

$~\underline{\text{Lemma 1}}$

Let $~k~$ be any **fixed, positive** real number.

Then, the $~\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 
\left[ ~n - \sqrt{n^2 - k} ~\right] = 0.$

**Proof** (without using conjugates)

For $~\displaystyle n > \sqrt{k},~$ you have that
$~\displaystyle n^2 > k \implies n > \dfrac{k}{n} \implies \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right) > 0.$

You also have that

$~\displaystyle \frac{k}{n^2} < 1 \implies \frac{k^2}{n^2} < k \implies $

$~\displaystyle n^2 - 2k + \frac{k^2}{n^2} < n^2 - k \implies \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right)^2 < n^2 - k \implies $

$\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right) < \sqrt{n^2 - k}.$

Further, continuing to assume that $~\displaystyle n > \sqrt{k},~$ you have that

$\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{2n} ~\right) > \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right) > 0.$

Then, you have that

$\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{2n} ~\right)^2 = n^2 - k + \frac{k^2}{4n^2} > (n^2 - k) \implies $

$\displaystyle \sqrt{n^2 - k} < \left( ~n - \frac{k}{2n} ~\right).$

So, for any $~\displaystyle n > \sqrt{k},~$ you have that

$\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right) < \sqrt{n^2 - k} < \left( ~n - \frac{k}{2n} ~\right).$

Then, with $~k~$ fixed, as $~n \to \infty,~$ you have that

$\displaystyle \sqrt{n^2 - k}~$ is squeezed between
$~\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{n} ~\right)~$
and
$~\displaystyle \left( ~n - \frac{k}{2n} ~\right).~$

Further, with $~k~$ fixed, as $~n \to \infty,~$ both
$~\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}~$ and $~\displaystyle \frac{k}{2n}~$ go to $~0.$

Therefore, as $~\displaystyle n \to \infty, ~n - \sqrt{n^2 - k}~$ goes to $~0.$

---

$\underline{\text{To Prove}}$

> $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left[ ~\sqrt{x^2 - 5x + 1} - x ~\right] = \frac{-5}{2}.~$

Let $~\displaystyle n = \left( ~x - \frac{5}{2} ~\right) \implies ~n^2 = \left( ~x^2 - 5x + \frac{25}{4} ~\right).$

Then, let $\displaystyle ~k = \frac{25}{4} - 1 \implies x^2 - 5x + 1 = n^2 - k.$

As $~x \to \infty,~$ so does $~n = \left( ~x - \dfrac{5}{2} \right).$

Then, by Lemma 1,

As $~\displaystyle x \to \infty, ~\left[ ~n - ~\sqrt{n^2 - k} ~\right] ~$ goes to $~0.~$

This implies that as $~\displaystyle x \to \infty, ~\left[ ~\left( ~x - \frac{5}{2} ~\right) - \sqrt{x^2 - 5x + 1} ~\right] ~$ goes to $~0.$

This implies that as $~\displaystyle x \to \infty, ~\left[ ~x - \sqrt{x^2 - 5x + 1} ~\right]~$ goes to $~\dfrac{5}{2}.$

This implies that as $~\displaystyle x \to \infty, ~\left[ ~\sqrt{x^2 - 5x + 1} - x ~\right]~$ goes to $~\dfrac{-5}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this is a special case what you can evaluate easy.

Since
$$x^2 - 5x + 1 = \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{41}{4}$$

Rewrite your original limit as below :
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \sqrt{\left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{41}{4}} - x \right)$$

and the constant "$\frac{41}{4}$" is too small, so we can eliminate this (Because we consider large $x$).

This means that for large $x$,
$$\left( \sqrt{\left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{41}{4}} - x \right) \approx \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right) - x = -\frac{5}{2} $$

and this implies the original limit converges to $-\frac{5}{2}$.

(You can verify this after learning taylor expansion.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x\stackrel{x=\frac1t}{=}\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt{t^2-5t+1}-1}{t}\\
\stackrel{\text{L'Hopital}}{=}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2t-5}{2\sqrt{t^2-5t+1}}=\frac{-5}{2}.$$

Comment: I hope that the L'Hopital rule is not banned by your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you have two functions $f,g$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0,$$

then it is **not** the case that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=0.$$

Something of the form $[\infty\cdot0]$ is called an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), and there are other examples of indeterminate forms out there. The point of them is that there is not way to get the answer from looking at the two involved limits separately; you need to know more about how they interact. Let us look at an example to illustrate why it fails. Suppose we are interested in the limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+5}}{x}.$$

We can see that we can write the function we're taking the limit of as a product with factors

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x^2+5},\quad g(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$$

But then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{2x^2+5}=\infty,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0,$$

however the limit of their product is

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+5}}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{2+\frac{5}{x^2}}=\sqrt{2}.$$

So you need to be careful when dealing with indeterminate forms, as they can really be anything.

Finally, I do want to remark that if

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=A,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=B,$$

where $A,B$ are both **finite**, then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)=AB.$$